# KVM based VPS crashes every 3-7 days. Is it an issue on VPS side or node's?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos7, server-crashes

I'm wondering could it be so that a VPS is a root cause of crashes which occurs every 3-7 days at night 03:00 - 04:00 time (kernel bug, or something else), or is it a node on which the virtual server is hosted (an issue with backend).

Details: KVM based VPS with CentOS 7, xfs hosted at VPS provider, who has a back-end and storage back-end infrastructure.

Usually it happens the following way, at once the running `kthreadd` process turns to `D`-status (i.e. uninterruptible sleep), and then we get messages like: `blocked for more than 120 seconds.` and high LA:

`May 21 03:08:01 vps root: root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   0:00 [kthreadd]
May 21 03:10:01 vps root: root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   0:00 [kthreadd]
May 21 03:12:01 vps root: root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May18   0:00 [kthreadd]
May 21 03:14:01 vps root: root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    May18   0:00 [kthreadd]
May 21 03:15:16 vps kernel: INFO: task kthreadd:2 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 21 03:15:16 vps kernel: kthreadd        D ffffffffffffffff     0     2      0 0x00000000
May 21 03:15:16 vps kernel: [<ffffffff810a65f2>] kthreadd+0x2b2/0x2f0
May 21 03:16:01 vps root: root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    May18   0:00 [kthreadd]
May 21 03:18:01 vps root: root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    May18   0:00 [kthreadd]
May 21 03:20:02 vps root: root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    May18   0:00 [kthreadd]`

here we have a call trace:

`May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: INFO: task kthreadd:2 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: kthreadd        D ffffffffffffffff     0     2      0 0x00000000
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: ffff88023413b4e0 0000000000000046 ffff880234120b80 ffff88023413bfd8
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: ffff88023413bfd8 ffff88023413bfd8 ffff880234120b80 ffff88023413b628
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: ffff88023413b630 7fffffffffffffff ffff880234120b80 ffffffffffffffff
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: Call Trace:
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff8163ae49>] schedule+0x29/0x70
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff81638b39>] schedule_timeout+0x209/0x2d0
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff8104fac3>] ? x2apic_send_IPI_mask+0x13/0x20
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff810b8a86>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x1b6/0x300
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff8163b216>] wait_for_completion+0x116/0x170
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff810b8c30>] ? wake_up_state+0x20/0x20
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff8109e7ac>] flush_work+0xfc/0x1c0
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff8109a7e0>] ? move_linked_works+0x90/0x90
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffffa021143a>] xlog_cil_force_lsn+0x8a/0x210 [xfs]
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffffa020fa7e>] _xfs_log_force_lsn+0x6e/0x2f0 [xfs]
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff81632005>] ? __slab_free+0x10e/0x277
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffffa020fd2e>] xfs_log_force_lsn+0x2e/0x90 [xfs]
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffffa0201fc9>] ? xfs_iunpin_wait+0x19/0x20 [xfs]
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffffa01fe4b7>] __xfs_iunpin_wait+0xa7/0x150 [xfs]
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff810a6b60>] ? wake_atomic_t_function+0x40/0x40
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffffa0201fc9>] xfs_iunpin_wait+0x19/0x20 [xfs]
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffffa01f684c>] xfs_reclaim_inode+0x8c/0x350 [xfs]
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffffa01f6d77>] xfs_reclaim_inodes_ag+0x267/0x390 [xfs]
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffffa01f7923>] xfs_reclaim_inodes_nr+0x33/0x40 [xfs]
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffffa0206895>] xfs_fs_free_cached_objects+0x15/0x20 [xfs]
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff811e0cd8>] prune_super+0xe8/0x170
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff8117c5c5>] shrink_slab+0x165/0x300
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff811d5f01>] ? vmpressure+0x21/0x90
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff8117f742>] do_try_to_free_pages+0x3c2/0x4e0
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff8117f95c>] try_to_free_pages+0xfc/0x180
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff8117365d>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x7fd/0xb90
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff81078d73>] copy_process.part.25+0x163/0x1610
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff810a5a20>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x140/0x140
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff8107a401>] do_fork+0xe1/0x320
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff8107a666>] kernel_thread+0x26/0x30
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff810a65f2>] kthreadd+0x2b2/0x2f0
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff810a6340>] ? kthread_create_on_cpu+0x60/0x60
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff81645e18>] ret_from_fork+0x58/0x90
May 18 04:14:37 vps kernel: [<ffffffff810a6340>] ? kthread_create_on_cpu+0x60/0x60`

A trick with dirty pages did not help.

Only hard reset helps to bring the server into operating state.

Could you help to understand whether it is an issue caused on VPS's side or node's?

Regards,
Alex.

Comment: I suspect the host has a problem with their storage. You should contact them.

Comment: I suspected the same, and contacted them several times. They say they do not have the issue with other 3000+ virtual servers and say we need to check the server on our side.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably a backup process or something storage-impacting happening at the *host* level. This is outside of your control and you should push the VPS provider for a solution.

If they can't resolve, consider going elsewhere.

Comment: I'm almost sure the things are exactly the way as you describe them (thank you for this). I'd like to find proofs of it, so that the server owner (it's not me actually) could believe them. Is there any chance to debug the incidents and collect 100% proofs that the case is caused at the host level. So that even hoster could not deny them.

Answer (score -2):

This is because you use Redhat/CentOS 7.2 and xfs. The kernel is not stabile like it was with 7.1. Current solution is migrate to ext4 if you want to use CentOS 7.2.

Comment: Hardly can I agree with that. What might be special with that specific server if I don't have issues with CentOS 7.2 on another servers? I've got at least 2 more servers with XFS and never had an issue with them. And every single from those 2 servers are hosted by different VPS companies. `Kernel 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64` and `/dev/vda1 on / type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)`.

Comment: Even more, we have several servers with the VPS provider (the exactly VPS provider with which we have an issue), and those other servers with CentOS 7.2 do not produce the same incidents. How would you explain it?